# type casting a built-up dictionary to a TypedDict

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have something like this (very simplified):

```
# mymodule.py

from typing import TypedDict, cast

D=TypedDict('D', {'x':int, 'y':int})
d = {}
d['x']=1
d['y']=2
d = cast(D, d)
```

But mypy complains:

`mymodule.py:9: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "D", variable has type "Dict[str, int]") Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)`

Shouldn't it be valid to cast a vanilla dictionary to a `TypedDict` subtype? If not, what is the correct way to "build-up" a dictionary and then declare its type afterwards?

Note that this is very simplified; in actuality the dictionary is being built from a more complicated algorithm than given above.

UPDATE: the problem seems to persist even when I change the variable name rather than try to cast the type.

```
# mymodule.py

from typing import TypedDict, cast

D=TypedDict('D', {'x':int, 'y':int})
d = {}
d['x']=1
d['y']=2
dd: D = d
```

`error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[str, int]", variable has type "D") Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)`

Comment: The issue isn't about the cast, the issue is about re-using ``d`` for two separate, incompatible types.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I see. So you think it would really be considered a best practice to change the variable name after the dictionary keys become fixed?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi see update question in just a second - mypy still complains if I change the variable name.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ah ha! I found the solution. I'll post an answer. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type-cast the initial dict before assigning it:

```py
from typing import TypeDict, cast

D = TypedDict('D', {'x':int, 'y':int})
d = cast(D, {})
d['x']=1
d['y']=2
```

This ensures that the variable `d` is directly inferred as "a `D`". Otherwise, inference immediately locks in the variable `d` as a `Dict[..., ...]` which cannot be changed later on.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @RicksupportsMonica You can directly use the ``d`` as the respective ``TypedDict``, even without assigning it to another variable. The caveat here is that the type checker assumes it is a ``D`` *even before its items are set* – so it will not warn against accessing items too early. Granted, with ``d = {}`` the error for accessing keys early is cryptic and not reliable, but it might in some cases be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

A solution seems to be to use a new variable name when the type cast is executed:

```
# mymodule.py

from typing import TypedDict, cast

D=TypedDict('D', {'x':int, 'y':int})
d = {}
d['x']=1
d['y']=2
dd: D = cast(D, d)
```

I suppose this enforces a best-practice of using a new variable name when signifying to the reader that the keys are not going to change from this point forward. It seems a little bit excessive to me, but I can understand why it would be advantageous in general for the type checker to treat things this way. EDIT: the accepted answer is a better way!